How to toggle Korean (Hangul) with Alt_R key
On Ubuntu 22.04, I used the ibus-Hangul input method preference to add Alt_R key as the toggle key to switch between English and Korean.
On Ubuntu 24.04, that stopped working. I was looking for ways to use Alt_R key as the toggle key.
I shall post the answer below.

Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please edit your question and remove your answer. Then post your answer as an answer that doesn't require any reputation points.

To clarify there is a button at the bottom of the question called Answer Your Own Question. Use that to post the answer.

Thanks. Done as suggested.

I found a solution. So I am answering my own question. (I cannot post replies to other users' similar question as I do not have enough reputation points to post replies to their questions).
Go to Settings --> Keyboard.
Under the "Input Sources", remove English (US). Leave Korean (Hangul) as the only Input Source.
Then everything should work as intended. You can use Alt_R as the toggle key.
I hope this helps.
